# Windows Server: scheduled backup not visible in Scheduled Tasks?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

I have set Windows Server 2016 Standard to perform a local backup to a usb drive on a nightly basis at 9pm. The last several runs failed because the destination was disconnected. I've since reconnected it and want to test to make sure it will resume working tonight, as well just get a known-good backup as soon as possible. How do I manually trigger the scheduled backup? I can't find it Task Scheduler.

Under *Computer Management >> Task Scheduler >> Task Status, Last 24 Hours* I see an item called "Microsoft-Windows-WindowsBackup". Double-clicking on it and right-click context menu don't offer anything. I also can't find a similarily named item under "Active Tasks".

Digging further down in the expanding left hand navigation tree there is no "Windows Backup" or "Backup" or other similar word combination that I've been able to find.

[image: wbadmin screenshot showing last failed and next scheduled backup for 9pm]

[image: Task Scheduler screenshot showing Windows Backup ran, but is not in Active Tasks]

[image: Backup not in table of contents]

Comment: I figured out that _Windows Backup >> Actions >> Backup Once_ can be used to copy scheduled backup settiongs and run immediately, which solves the "make a backup right now" problem but that's not quite the same as "testing the scheduled task will run".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft-Windows-WindowsBackup item you see in the Tack Scheduler's status log is, indeed, the thing you are looking for. That's the name of the task.

I don't use Windows Backup, but I installed the feature on a test server to see where it records its scheduled tasks. They appear in the Task Scheduler, under `Task Scheduler Library --> Microsoft --> Windows --> Backup`.

[image: Task Scheduler]

Maybe it is in a different place for you. But I can't find a way to drill in to the task as listed in the status log to find out where it lives in the hierarchy.

I'm wondering if somehow your Task Scheduler control panel got set to only show certain categories. But I can't find any option for not displaying all of the sub-items under `Task Scheduler Library --> Microsoft --> Windows`.  In your screenshot, it would be right where you broke it up. Can you check again, and add a screenshot showing all the way from the A's to the C's?

Also, I see it in the same place using both the Task Scheduler interface and the Task Scheduler section of the more general Computer Management interface. So that doesn't explain your not seeing it.

If we can get it to appear in the Active Tasks list -- below the Task Status section -- that would give us the location in one of the fields of that list. But it doesn't appear for me in that list, even though it appears to meet the criteria -- enabled and not expired.

Comment: Well of all the #$@^!. Today [Backup] is in the expanded tree. I'm certain it wasn't the day I was struggling with this. Unfortunately I did not save the intermediate screenshot which had the entire list so all I have to back me up (pun intended) is my say so. ...Thank you for taking the time to test and follow up.